# Mocking repository function leads to null pointer exception despite using when and thenReturn

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

My `ServiceImpl` looks like this:

```java
@Service
public class GuildUsersServiceImpl implements GuildUsersService {

  @Autowired
  private final GuildUsersRepository guildUsersRepository;

  @Autowired
  private GuildService guildService;

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private GuildUserRoleTypeService guildUserRoleTypeService;

  @Autowired
  public GuildUsersServiceImpl(final GuildUsersRepository guildUsersRepository) {
    this.guildUsersRepository = guildUsersRepository;
  }

  public GuildUsers create(GuildUsers guildUser) {
    return this.guildUsersRepository.save(guildUser);
  }
}
```

And my service test for `create` looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class GuildUsersServiceTest {
  
  @Mock private GuildUsersRepository guildUsersRepository;
  
  @Mock private UserService userService;

  @Mock private GuildService guildService;
  
  @Mock private GuildUserRoleTypeService guildUserRoleTypeService;

  @InjectMocks private GuildUsersServiceImpl guildUsersService;
  
  @Before
  public void setUp(){
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
  
  @Test
  public void createTest() {
    GuildUsers guildUsers = mockGuildUsers();
    when(guildUsersRepository.save(guildUsers)).thenReturn(guildUsers);
    GuildUsers dbGuildUsers = guildUsersService.create(guildUsers);
    assertEquals(dbGuildUsers.getId(),guildUsers.getId());
  }
}
```

I am using `jUnit4`. Despite using `when(guildUsersRepository.save(guildUsers)).thenReturn(guildUsers);` in the test, I run into a Null Pointer Exception with the following trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.project.entities.domain.GuildUsers.getId()" because "dbGuildUsers" is null
```

I suspect something is wrong with how I have mocked the `@Autowired` classes. What needs to be done differently while mocking classes in the Test class ?

At the same time I want the services in the following test case to work as well :

```java
@Test
  public void createTest1() {
    GuildUsers guildUsers = mockGuildUsers();
    GuildUsersWithoutGuildIdRequestDTO guildUsersWithoutGuildIdRequestDTO = new  GuildUsersWithoutGuildIdRequestDTO();
    guildUsersWithoutGuildIdRequestDTO.setUserId(guildUsers.getUser().getId());
    guildUsersWithoutGuildIdRequestDTO.setGuildUserRoleTypeId(guildUsers.getGuildUserRoleType().getId());
    
    when(guildService.get(guildUsers.getGuild().getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(guildUsers.getGuild()));
    when(guildRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(guildUsers.getGuild()));
    when(userService.get(guildUsers.getUser().getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(guildUsers.getUser()));
    when(guildUsersRepository.findById(guildUsers.getId())).thenReturn(null);
    when(guildUserRoleTypeService.get(guildUsers.getGuildUserRoleType().getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(guildUsers.getGuildUserRoleType()));
    when(guildUsersRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(guildUsers);
    
    GuildUsersResponseDTO dbGuildUsersResponseDTO = 
        guildUsersService.create(guildUsers.getGuild().getId(),guildUsersWithoutGuildIdRequestDTO);
    assertEquals(dbGuildUsersResponseDTO.getGuildUserRoleType(),guildUsers.getGuildUserRoleType());
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you did field injection as well as constructor injection at the same time. You should remove one of them first, for instance:

```
@Service
public class GuildUsersServiceImpl implements GuildUsersService {
  
  //@Autowired - removed
  private final GuildUsersRepository guildUsersRepository;

  @Autowired
  private GuildService guildService;

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private GuildUserRoleTypeService guildUserRoleTypeService;

  //@Autowired - removed
  public GuildUsersServiceImpl(final GuildUsersRepository guildUsersRepository) {
    this.guildUsersRepository = guildUsersRepository;
  }

  public GuildUsers create(GuildUsers guildUser) {
    return this.guildUsersRepository.save(guildUser);
  }
}
```

OR remove the constructor to add:

````
  @Autowired 
  private final GuildUsersRepository guildUsersRepository;```
````

Comment: That didn't work. In either case I am passing only that instance of the object and hence shouldn't need to invoke `any()`

Comment: How should the other `@Autowired` services be mocked and injected because although your answer solves the issue with the repository, the other autowired services start throwing NPE

Comment: oh, did you make modifications on the test or is as it was?

Comment: The issue pops up in a different test case. Adding the same to my question.

Comment: can you be specific just to start with one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223579/discussion-between-fireball-1-and-aman).

Answer (score 0):

InjectMock documentation clearly says: "Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection, setter injection, or property injection in order and as described below."

In your case, it apparently chooses property injection, hence guildUserRoleTypeService remains uninitialised. Mixing property and constructor injection is not a good idea as pointed above.

To improve the general design and testability of your GuildUsersServiceImpl, I would suggest to stick with constructor injection. This way you can:
a) Declare all the fields as private final, so they will always be set once the object is created, avoiding race conditions and NPEs.
b) Initialise GuildUsersServiceImpl in the test using a proper constructor rather than InjectMocks.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for other people that also wasted an afternoon on trying to get a repository to return what they configured. What ended up being the thing I had to do is rather than annotating the repository with `@Mock` I had to use the `@MockBean` annotation for the Mockito/Spring combination to work properly.

As per javadoc of `@MockBean`:

> When @MockBean is used on a field, as well as being registered in the application context, the mock will also be injected into the field.